onSuccess function is not being called when I try to login with useGoogleLogin
Here is my component. When I try to login with google, it redirects to http://localhost:3000/sign-in with all google info in the url, but does not call the onSuccess or onError functions. Please help to resolve the issue. I use @react-oauth/google library.
import { useGoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';

export const SignInPage = () => {
  const login = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: tokenResponse => console.log(tokenResponse),
    onError: () => {
      console.log('Login Failed');
    },
    flow: 'auth-code',
    ux_mode: 'redirect',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/sign-in',
  });

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => login()}>
      Google login
    </button>
  );
};

